# Could anyone advise a good resource for understanding magento's config xml files

Tags: xml, configuration, magento, config

Hey there, I am really having some issues overriding the shipping block in the checkout module of magento. 
Could you please advise some resourses where I can get knowledge about the structure of magento xml files.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alan Storm's [original blog post](http://alanstorm.com/magento_config) and subsequent [official knowledge base article](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-2-the-magento-config) are about as good as they get.